# React key item list error, even after I added the required Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, material-ui, key

Here is the list container example

```
import { List, ListItemText, ListItem } from '@mui/material';

import FooterItem from './FooterItem';

const FooterList = ({ title, items }) => {
    return (
        <List>
            {/* HEADING */}
            <ListItem key={title}>
                <ListItemText sx={{ marginLeft: 2 }}>{title}</ListItemText>
            </ListItem>
            {/* LIST */}
            {items.map((item) => {
                return <FooterItem text={item.text} url={item.url} id={item.id}></FooterItem>;
            })}
        </List>
    );
};
export default FooterList;
```

Here is the list item example with the key on the `ListItem` component

```
  import { ListItemText, ListItem, ListItemButton } from '@mui/material';
const FooterItem = ({ id, text, url }) => {
    console.log(id);
    return (
        <ListItem key={id}>
            <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemText href={url} sx={{ color: 'white', marginTop: '0' }}>
                    {text}
                </ListItemText>
            </ListItemButton>
        </ListItem>
    );
};

export default FooterItem;
```

As you can see even after adding the key to `ListItem` the console is showing react key item list error.
[image]

Comment: Hey there, can you provide the error screenshot. This will help in finding where the error is actually occurring.

Comment: @Milanpatel not yet, I finally managed to formulate the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Update]**

Based on your updated question here is what you need to change inside your `FooterList` i.e. list container component.

```
import { List, ListItemText, ListItem } from '@mui/material';

import FooterItem from './FooterItem';

const FooterList = ({ title, items }) => {
    return (
        <List>
            {/* HEADING */}
            <ListItem key={title}>
                <ListItemText sx={{ marginLeft: 2 }}>{title}</ListItemText>
            </ListItem>
            {/* LIST */}
            {items.map((item, index) => {
                return <FooterItem text={item.text} url={item.url} key={item.id} />;
            })}
        </List>
    );
};
export default FooterList;
```

And you can remove `key={id}` from your `ListItem` component. If despite adding key in your `FooterList` component, you are getting the error means the value you are providing as a key might not be unique so you can use index as a key which should be unique. But be aware of [some pitfalls](https://dev.to/shiv1998/why-not-to-use-index-as-key-in-react-lists-practical-example-3e66) of using index as a key as it might give you unexpected behavior in some cases. Anyways from what I see your code can easily survive using index as a key so no problem. But in general practice you should not use index as a key and always use unique key for it.

**[Old]**

Based on the code you provided, I can see that you have applied the key attribute to `ListItemButton` which here is not the cause of the error you are getting inside console. The problem is with the calling component i.e, from the component you are rendering `FooterItem` by adding it.

So suppose you have a parent component where you are looping through items and rendering `FooterItem` inside that loop here is what you should be doing.

For example you have `HomePage` component and inside that you are including your `FooterItem` component. The code should look like this.

`HomePage` component

```
const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        {footerItems.map((item, index) => {
            return <FooterItem key={index} text={item.text} url={item.url}>
        })}
    )
}
```

Note that here I have added key attribute to the parent component from where `FooterItem` is getting called and not in the `FooterItem` itself.

I hope this helps. This was based on the details you provided. If you are still facing problem, would you mind posting some portion of parent component where you are including `FooterItem` so I can help you in better way.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I edited the code snippets and added the class list component. If you can double-check the actual code now will present the issue better

Comment: Oh I have added a copy pasta example and some more info. you can check it